# Get list of packages referenced by dotnet project in code c#

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface

I would like to create my custom dotnet tool and in its implementation, I need to get the list of packages referenced by the project (and the packages they depend on).
From the command line, I can run something like this to get that list:

```
dotnet list package --include-transitive
```

I was trying to find how this is implemented in the dotnet sdk repo but the repo is so massive it is very difficult to find anything.

Does anyone have an idea where this is implemented or, even better, can you provide a C# code example on how to get this list in code.

Comment: If this is only for sdk-style projects (is it?) , why not parse project.assets.json directly? I remember that there are some Nuget packages/classes that can parse it.

Comment: Yes it is only for ask style projects. If you have an example of code parsing the project.asset.json file I think it would be an acceptable answer. I would prefer the actual method used by the sdk which I guess parses the same file anyway

Comment: This should get you started https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/analyze-dotnet-project-dependencies-part-2/ I now remembered the name of the class that deals with dependencies on the nugget side: LockFile. If you prefer jumping into code: https://github.com/jerriepelser-blog/AnalyzeDotNetProject/blob/master/LockFileService.cs . I am not posting it as an answer since it's not my code.

Answer (score 3):

I followed the suggestion from @alexandru-clonțea and tried out the code on [github](https://github.com/jerriepelser-blog/AnalyzeDotNetProject).
In my opinion it actually answers the question correctly.
It involves running dotnet restore on the project and generate a dependency graph file and then reading the file using the NuGet.ProjectModel library.
The core part of the code that reads the dependencies is this:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using NuGet.ProjectModel;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    /// <remarks>
    /// Credit for the stuff happening in here goes to the https://github.com/jaredcnance/dotnet-status project
    /// </remarks>
    public class DependencyGraphService
    {
        public DependencyGraphSpec GenerateDependencyGraph(string projectPath)
        {
            var tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetTempFileName());
            var arguments = new[] {"msbuild", $"\"{projectPath}\"", "/t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile", $"/p:RestoreGraphOutputPath={tempFile}"};

            try
            {
                var runStatus = DotNetRunner.Run(Path.GetDirectoryName(projectPath), arguments);

                if (!runStatus.IsSuccess)
                    throw new Exception($"Unable to process the the project `{projectPath}. Are you sure this is a valid .NET Core or .NET Standard project type?" +
                                        $"\r\n\r\nHere is the full error message returned from the Microsoft Build Engine:\r\n\r\n" + runStatus.Output);

                return new DependencyGraphSpec(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(File.ReadAllText(tempFile)));
            }
            finally
            {
                if(File.Exists(tempFile))
                    File.Delete(tempFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```